# How to automatically skip rows that have non-floating values using pandas read_csv in python?

Tags: python, pandas, file

I have thousands of the `.csv` files that contain a massive amount of sensory data, all in floating numbers. But there are also some rows in some files show date and time information, and it appears in different locations in files as shown in the image below:

[image]

In the above image, the first two rows are in the beginning but can be at other locations for other files. This kind of non-floating rows should be skipped when reading the files using pandas `read_csv` function to avoid errors.

I used `skiprows` function to skip specific rows at constant row index, but the problem that the unwanted rows are variable in location through files.

```py
        for j in range(len(all_list)):
        path = os.path.join(path, all_list[j])
        # print(path)
        df_data = pd.read_csv(path, skiprows=[0, 1], header=None)
        print("data shape: ", df_data.shape)
```

My question is:
How can I read only the floating-based rows and automatically skip the non-floating data from all files?

Comment: you probably have to use the python `csv` module and iterate through each line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You give any arbitrary/fixed header name while importing to `pandas.read_csv` and then process the data frame to drop all non-float values

Given Data:
[image]

```
 import pandas as pd
 
 sample_csv=pd.read_csv('USERS.CSV',names=[X','Y','Z'], index_col=False)
 def is_float(x):
    try:
        float(x)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True

sample_csv[sample_csv.applymap(lambda x: is_float(x))].dropna()
```

The Output:
[image]

And finally, you can adjust the headers.

Comment: Yeah, this solution works fine with me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd  

# read csv
df_data = pd.read_csv(path, header=None)

# parse to numeric and set invalid values to NaN
df_data = df_data.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

# drop rows that contain NaN values
df_data = df_data.dropna()
```

Comment: I'd love if read_csv() had an errors='coerce', but this is almost as good. Obviously assumes your entire dataframe is numeric.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the csv as text, remove the unwanted lines and read it with pandas:

```
for j in range(len(all_list)):
    path = os.path.join(path, all_list[j])
    # print(path)
    with open(path) as f:
        l=f.readlines()
    l=[x[:-1].split(',') for x in l if '$' not in x]
   
    df_data = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
    print("data shape: ", df_data.shape)
```

I added if `'$' not in x` as a filter for unwanted rows, you need to replace it if it is not adequate.

Comment: Yeah, the performance is important to us since we have thousands of files. Your answer is iterating to read all rows and then write them but this will slow the performance. Any other idea?

Comment: I improved my solution regarding performance, it now loads dataframe directly from the list. Please check again

Comment: Don't use `.readlines` iterate directly over the file object.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure your pandas dataframe will have the incorrect dtypes

Answer (score 0):

If your data doesn't contain missing values (or if they are going to be dropped anyway), you could make use of `read_csv`'s `converters`-functionality with a converter like

```py
def conv(x):
    try:
        return float(x)
    except:
        return None
```

and a subsequent `.dropna()`. If `NA`s are a concern, you could use a different signal value to return and filter those out via some boolean indexing magic